# printf format specifier for max double width

Tags: c++, c

I have the following array:

```
float a[]={ 1.123 12.123, 123.123, 12345.123};
```

How do I create the following output (crop the fractional part):

```
1.123
12.12
123.1
12345
```

Comment: Did you have a question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Its a good question but please post the code what you've tried and didn't work so that it will be easy to spot the error.

Comment: Tailored to work *only* for that input, [here ya go](http://ideone.com/7ztY4G)

Comment: And what should be the output for `0.000123`.

Answer (score 2):

```
float a[]={ 1.123, 12.123, 123.123, 12345.123};
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
    int digits = 4 - log10(a[i]);
    digits = digits < 0 ? 0 : digits;
    digits = digits > 3 ? 3 : digits;
    printf("%.*f\n",digits,a[i]);
}
```

Comment: the header file for `log10` ? for linux

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    float a[]= { 1.123, 12.123, 123.123, 12345.123};

    int i;
    char floatString[100] = {0};

    for (i=0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
        memset(floatString, 0, sizeof(floatString));
        sprintf(floatString, "%f", a[i]);
        floatString[5] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", floatString);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better question, did you *run* this on a 64bit platform? The third value in the array overflows the buffer into the index variable `i` of  the for-loop. See it [on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/lhQOjE)

Comment: @WhozCraig. Fixed - sprintf expects buffer large enough to fit results in. Increased buffer size solves overflow problem. Or we need to use `snprintf` which would be safe, but it is non-standard. So third alternative is to write own portable `snprintf`. But it is out of the scope of this example :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{  
  float a[]={ 1.123, 12.123, 123.123, 12345.123}; 

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << a[i];
    std::string s;
    ss >> s;
    s.resize(5);        // it only works with 99999
    cout << s << "\n";
  }
  cout << endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this,

```
printf("%1.3f\n%2.2f\n%3.1f\n%5.0f\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snprintf` in this way:

```
int main()
{
    float a[]= { 1.123, 12.123, 123.123, 12345.123 };
    char buf[8];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++) {
        snprintf(buf, 6, "%f", a[i]);
        printf("%s\n",buf);
    }
}
```